# How to loop through an observable in Angular 4

Tags: angular, loops, rxjs, observable

I have an array of sections and I'm trying to get and display all the items under each sections. It seems like a pretty simple take. Here is my code:

```
//my ngOnInit call this function 
this.sectionService.GetItemList(this.selectedSectionList, this.culture)       
        .subscribe(
           (itemList: ItemBySection[]) => {
               this.itemBySection = itemList;

               this.loaded = true;
            },
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = error, () => 
console.log("loaded")
        );

//this is my function in my service
 public GetItemList(SectionItems: Sections[], strCulture): Observable<ItemBySection[]> {

    let resultObservable
    for (var SectionItem in SectionItems) {
        let url = environment.portalWebServiceURL + "api/section/" + SectionItems[SectionItem].sectionItemID.toString() + "/" + strCulture;
        resultObservable = this.http.get(url)
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .mergeMap(res => <ItemBySection[]>res.json());
    }

    return resultObservable; 

}
```

Maybe my explanation above wasn't too clear 
So what I'm trying to do is call my web service multiple time within a loop and concatenate the result into one list. Maybe this will help.

```
for all my sectionIDs {
  call url web service with sectionID 
  receive results from server
  add the results in my item array
}
finally display all items.
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the problem is your http stream: res.json() returns the body of the response parsed as json.
So you should use .map() operator, not .mergeMap() operator.

The former one simply apply the transformation function to each stream data and pipe the result (and that's what you need), the latter one projects all the values of one observable into your stream (and that's not what you need).

Some references:

- flatMap (that is the an alias of mergeMap): https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/flatmap.html
- map: https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/map.html

Hope it helps :)

** UPDATE **

Ok, i misunderstood your needs: you need to join all the http responses in an array of responses.
You could do something like that:

```
public GetItemList(SectionItems: Sections[], strCulture): Observable<ItemBySection[]> {
    const resultObservables = []
    for (var SectionItem in SectionItems) {
        let url = environment.portalWebServiceURL + "api/section/" + SectionItems[SectionItem].sectionItemID.toString() + "/" + strCulture;
        const response = this.http.get(url)
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .map(res => <ItemBySection>res.json());
        resultObservables.push(response)
    }
    return Observable.forkJoin(resultObservables); 
}
```

I wrote this code directly here, so it may not work, but the idea behind it should be what you need :)

Comment: If I use map the system only picks up the items from the first section but if I use mergeMap I get this error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays." I just want to display all the items for all the selected sections. Does that make sense? How do I merge or concatenate all the records that I receive from my web service into 1 observable?

Comment: Ok, now i unserstood your needs, but your code does something dirrefent: every loop of SectionItems you're overwriting the resultObservable variable.
I try to update my answer accordingly :)

Comment: That was great thank you Lorenzo. Your answer separated each call into arrays. I just have to figure out how to concatenate these arrays. I think I should be able to figure that out. Thanks again.